# Problem with Hadoop Streaming -file option for Java class files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am struggling with a very basic issue in hadoop
streaming in the "-file" option.

First I tried the very basic example in streaming:

hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar
contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar -mapper
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \ -reducer /bin/wc
-inputformat KeyValueTextInputFormat -input gutenberg/* -output
gutenberg-outputtstchk22

which worked absolutely fine.

Then I copied the IdentityMapper.java source code and compiled it.
Then I placed this class file in the /home/hadoop folder and executed the
following in the terminal.

hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar
contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar -file
~/IdentityMapper.class -mapper IdentityMapper.class \ -reducer /bin/wc
-inputformat KeyValueTextInputFormat -input gutenberg/* -output
gutenberg-outputtstch6

The execution failed with the following error in the  stderr file:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "IdentityMapper.class":
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Then again I tried it by copying the IdentityMapper.class file in the
hadoop installation and executed the following:

hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar
contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar -file
IdentityMapper.class -mapper IdentityMapper.class \ -reducer /bin/wc
-inputformat KeyValueTextInputFormat -input gutenberg/* -output
gutenberg-outputtstch5

But unfortunately again I got the same error.

It would be great if you can help me with it as I cannot move any further
without overcoming this.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to compile the class? It is already compiled in the hadoop jars. You are just passing the classname (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper), because Hadoop uses reflection to instantiate a new instance of this mapping class.

You have to make sure that this is lying in the classpath e.g. within a jar you are passing the job.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know that the jar is already there, I am trying this after I tried hadoop-streaming for a different class file which failed, so to identify if there is something wrong with the class file itself or with the way I am using it

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791467/java-io-ioexception-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory-eroor-in-hadoop-streaming/), you can't really use -file to send over jars as hadoop doesn't support multiple jars (that were not already in the CLASSPATH), check the [streaming docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/streaming.html#How+do+I+provide+my+own+input%2Foutput+format+with+streaming%3F):

> At least as late as version 0.14, Hadoop does not support multiple jar files. So, when specifying your own custom classes you will have to pack them along with the streaming jar and use the custom jar instead of the default hadoop streaming jar.

Comment: Thanks, but even i am trying for class files (instead of jars), I am getting the same error as detailed below:                                                             I executed the following command on the terminal:

hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar -file /home/hadoop/codes/MapperTst.class -mapper /home/hadoop/codes/MapperTst.class -file /home/hadoop/codes/ReducerTst.class -reducer /home/hadoop/codes/ReducerTst.class -input gutenberg/* -output gutenberg-outputtstch27

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the same underlying problem. You'll need to package your custom class in custom hadoop-streaming.jar and pass it that way.

Comment: But I was wondering if does not allow to send jars or class files through the file option how will I be able to pass any libraries that may be required by the mapper also I think that hadoop packs any file that is send through that is send through the -file option in the job jar....please advice

Comment: You need to combine all of the libraries and classes you need into one jar - and in the Streaming case that needs to be the Streaming jar. If you are not using Streaming then it would be all of your custom libraries. Streaming is really just a custom jar for running non-native Hadoop M/R jobs - usually non Java languages like Python or Perl. If you are going to be writing Java M/R jobs you should write them using the Hadoop MapReduce classes.

Answer (score 1):

I met similar problem. And adding the jar file to HADOOP_CLASSPATH fixed the issue.
More info please refer this: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/