# java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory eroor in Hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Please help with the "-file" option issue of hadoop streaming (mentioned in the link below). just to update, I know that the jar is already there, I am trying this after I tried hadoop-streaming for a different class file which failed, so to identify if there is something wrong with the class file itself or with the way I am using it. if you need the stderr file please let me know.

[Problem with Hadoop Streaming -file option for Java class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790110/problem-with-hadoop-streaming-file-option-for-java-class-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't really use -file to send over jars as hadoop doesn't support multiple jars (that were not already in the CLASSPATH), check the [streaming docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/streaming.html#How+do+I+provide+my+own+input%2Foutput+format+with+streaming%3F):

> At least as late as version 0.14, Hadoop does not support multiple jar files. So, when specifying your own custom classes you will have to pack them along with the streaming jar and use the custom jar instead of the default hadoop streaming jar.

Comment: Thanks, but even i am trying for class files (instead of jars), I am getting the same error as detailed below

Comment: Answered in your original [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790110/problem-with-hadoop-streaming-file-option-for-java-class-files)

Answer (score 1):

To add more than one jar file to the CLASSPATH.. you could use the -libjars options as specified in the hadoop [tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html) (search for the word "libjar" on the page).